# Argument list too long when running ls -d "$PWD"/* command

Tags: command-line, ls

I'm trying to execute

```
ls -d "$PWD"/* > formmlFileList43k.list
```

But I get the following error:

`bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long`

I've read using a pipe won't have such limitation, how can I use pipe which will accomplish the same as:

```
ls -d "$PWD"/* > formmlFileList43k.list
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have too many items in the directory. That causes the shell to expand `*` into a command line argument that exceeds ARG_MAX bytes:

```
$ grep ARG_MAX /usr/include/linux/limits.h
#define ARG_MAX       131072    /* # bytes of args + environ for exec() */
```

I suggest you to use `find` as a workaround:

```
$ find "${PWD}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 > formmlFileList43k.list
```

---

**EDIT:** @hagello wrote an important note about filenames beginning with a dot. These files should be excluded from the `find` output. So, the correct workaround is:

```
$ find "${PWD}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 '!' -name '.*' > formmlFileList43k.list
```

Comment: You should be aware that find prints the dot files while "ls" by default does not.